# Can't decrypt internal memory; no hard reset available

Tags: root-access, encryption

I have an LG Access (LGL31L) (Tracphone) running 4.2.4 that I recently rooted using towelroot. The phone's memory is encrypted, and after getting somewhat over-zealous with the new root access I disabled something important and after rebooting my phone all I can do is get the screen that says "Enter PIN/Password to decrypt". But before I get to that screen the phone says "unfortunately, settings has stopped"...

I can still pull up the emergency dialer, the touch screen still works, but I can't get the phone to pull up it's keyboard to input the decryption PIN. It doesn't help that this phone is rare enough that I can't seem to find a custom recovery and it's even worse because there is no way to perform a hard data reset, only via the settings menu (which I can't get to...)

If anyone has any ideas I would be extremely grateful!!!

Comment: "*running 4.2.4*" -- what did I see? Please [edit].

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to factory reset your phone. Go to the dial pad and type in    `*#*#7780#*#*`     and this will automatically factory reset the device.

WARNING: This will wipe everything on your phone. So proceed with caution.